# Use variable as key word for grep function

Tags: variables, search, grep

I have successfully used this syntax to assign and locate keywords.  I'd like to take the same approach but instead of knowing the word in advance like in the example below, I want to pass the word/expression as a variable, for example replacing *options*, with a var.  How would I do that?

phrase <- "(options) ([^ ]+)"

Comment: i <- 1
while (i<4)

  {
  phrase <- paste0("(", term_i, ") ([^ ]+)")
  
  imp_term_i_df <- improve_table$imp_fb%>%
    str_subset(phrase)
  
  imp_term_i_sample<- sample_n(imp_term_i_df, 10)
  
  library(DT)
  datatable((imp_term_i_sample),
            colnames = c('Row',term_i),rownames = FALSE, 
            options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-left', targets = 0:1)),dom ='t',pageLength = 10, searchHighlight = TRUE, search = list(search = term_i)))
   i=i+1
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste0`:

```r
phrase <- paste0("(", optionsVar, ") ([^ ]+)")
```

Also, note that `[^ ]+` matches one or more chars other than spaces, but you can probably replace it with `\\S+`, one or more non-whitespace chars. Same with the literal space: `\\s` or `\\s+` might prove more flexible.

Comment: That worked great.  Is there any way to allow for the optionsVar to be run by a for loop by adding i to OptionsVar_i.  I tried it with the current syntax and it did not work.  Thank you for your first answer though!

Comment: @TimothyFisher Please update the question with your current non-working code and specify the expected result. You almost never use loops in R, there are either vectorized functions or you use `[slm]apply`.

Comment: @TimothyFisher Just use a for loop then. `for (options in optionsVar) {   phrase <- paste0("(", options, ") ([^ ]+)")  }`.